# What is the correct term in English prose for HTML page or html page?

Tags: capitalization, acronyms

I've seen prose referring to HTML pages and html pages. What is the correct English written description (assuming in modern English - in a written technical book) for an html page?

> Open the HTML page in your browser

or

> Open the html page in your browser

**Assumptions**:

- I understand this is an acronym and so should be capitalized
- I also understand that as this is used in idiomatic English for people typing in web pages, it is frequently used and understood in the lowercase form

My question is: **What is the correct term in English prose for HTML page or html page?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML is an acronym, and should be capitalised. If you really wanted a lower case equivalent, I would just say "Open the web page".

It's like calling the USA and UK the Usa and Uk, which could be misleading.

EDIT: Since most files are saved with a lower case extension, you could say " Open the .html page ", but this is purely a reference to the extension to avoid confusion.